# Spatial offset of a virtual object with Opengl ES perspective

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality

**Context:** I'm currently working on a Augmented Reality (AR) application using OpenGL ES 2.0 and some AR glasses running on Android. My goal is to display a virtual cursor at the tip of a real object : a screwdriver. Both the glasses and the screwdriver locations are tracked by a fixed external camera. The left image just below can give you an idea of the setup.

[image: Drawing of the setup I'm using]

**Things that are working:** So far, I'm able to display a virtual 3D object (for example a cube) at a given location in space. For example, I am able to position it at (more or less 1cm from) the tip of a tracked screwdriver. When I just rotate the head, the virtual cube gives the impression to "stay at the same place" in the real world, which is nice. This behavior is what I expected, and is consistent with its real-world anchor.

**Issue:** However, when I do a translation with the head (and thus a translation of the opengl camera), the cube seems to have a strange spatial offset, like if it was shifted from the object's tip (case 2 in the drawing above). This shift can be pretty significant (until 5 or 6 cm), and unconsistent with the real-world. But if I align the object exactly with any of the camera axis, the cube seems well-placed at the tip of the object, which confuses me.

**Question:** Is it just a strange visual perspective effect ? How can it work with head rotations but not head translations ? Did I miss something about perspective projection in OpenGL ES ?

**Implementation details** The fixed external camera is the origin of world coordinates. It is really precise, and gives me both the world-space position and rotation of each object (including the glasses and the screwdriver). To be more precise, it continuously send this data via Bluetooth to my Android program to make sure what the user can see is up-to-date.

In the case 1, this works like a charm: the camera correctly detects that the screwdriver is at position (0, 0, 1 meter) and whatever rotation for example, I display a cube centered around that position, and it appears correctly placed. But after a head translation (case 2), the screwdriver is still detected at the correct position (it didn't move after all), but the cube is shifted in a way that does not make sense to me.

If it was a small offset, I would put that on an accumulation of small errors, but here it seems to big to be the only explanation. Depending on the head translation I do, the cube gains a different offset and overall give the impression not to have a single fixed position in the world.

I am using *perspective projection* with the FOV and aspect ration of the AR glasses. The position of the opengl camera is set to the position of the AR glasses, and the *Look-at* values are computed according to the direction the head is currently facing.

If I modify the FOV, I loose the expected behavior I have about head rotations and correct positionning. Finally, I am using the glasses as a stereo display.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you are computing the virtual cursor 3D world space position ? I suppose your system is able to give you the world space position & rotation of the screwdriver so I guess you are using those to update the 3D position of the cursor that you then render as a cube ?

Comment: You are right: the external camera gives me both the world space position and the rotation of all tracked objects, including the AR glasses and the screwdriver. I will update the last part of my answer to be more precise.